# Show specific Bootstrap modal when radio button is selected and click on save button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a boostrap modal into my html file, where the bootstrap modal will be opened when the user selects on a specific radio input and then hit on the save button.

the modal will only show once pressed on the save button and if the correct radio input is selected

I have here the fiddle so you can see my UI

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/bm17cmxj/1/>
```

cheers!

Answer (score 3):

OK. so i tried researching more about jQuery and found a solution in my problem

here is the code that works exactly on what i would like to happen

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".saveButton").click(function(){
        if($('#optionsRadios2').is(':checked')) { 
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }

    });
});
```

see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/bm17cmxj/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="**option1**">
                Option 1
              </label>
            </div> 
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="**option1**">
```

both values are option1. cut and paste is not always your friend :)

Comment: they also have the same id which is also a big nono